# how to add first application in apple store using in-app-purchase

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am new in iTunes store. and i have create a iphone application and i want to use apple In-App-Purchase in my application and its my first application. and  i want to submit this application to apple store. but it needs minimum one paid application submitted on apple store before use In-App-Purchase. so can any one suggest how i submit my first application on apple store with in-app-purchase.

Thanks